# Hiding an article in a Joomla search results

Tags: search, joomla3.0

i have a joomla site with a page that is hidden from the public, meaning you cannot get to it unless you have the URL.

however, if you do a search via the default joomla search module, the page shows up in the results.

is it possible to hide a single page from being displayed in the search results?

Comment: Assuming you are using Smart Search, this has been answered at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4060/120

Comment: not using smart search. using DEFAULT search module. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

This plug-in module, following an improved version of the default content search engine! Included in the options you want!
http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/improved-content-search